# Do I need to have a Parent declaration in my POM.xml?

Tags: maven

I've declared my project as a pom.xml to define the parent, and it triggers a reactor build of all the included modules. Everything builds fine and works as expected. It builds in the right order, all the tests run correctly, and I get my expected output.

One of the projects is a shared library. I don't want to add a `<parent>` declaration here, so I didn't. It all still works.

My Question: do I need to bother adding a parent project declaration in any of my sub-projects? What are the pros and cons of having a two-way relationship between the projects? If I don't add the declarations, am I going to make it harder later when something stops working?

Rephrased into a single question: why bother with `<parent>` configuration in module pom.xml files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is related to the difference between Project Inheritance vs. Project Aggregation. The `<parent>` reference defines the inheritance relationship. The `<modules>` section in the parent pom.xml defines the aggregation. They are different.

If you do not have the `<parent>` configuration in the module pom.xml, it will not inherit the parent pom.xml configuration. So let's say you define the version of a dependency in the parent pom in the `<dependencyManagement>` section, the module pom.xml without parent reference will not inherit that. Or if all your child modules need to use a common library, you can define the dependency in the parent pom.xml. However, the module pom.xml without the parent reference will not inherit that dependency either.

For details, please check out [Project Inheritance vs Project Aggregation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance_vs_Project_Aggregation)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you configure your build. If you have a correctly configured parent pom, basic information like `version and groupid` can be shared between your projects.

You can define the project wide configuration information that should be shared in all the modules in the project. For example:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>groupd.id</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact.id</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>version</version>
```

With that in place, you do not have duplicate that information in the module projects. The same information can be referenced like so:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact.id</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
</parent>
```

Remember that the parent pom can be used to shared more information than specified above. You can do dependency management, plugin management and even define re-usable profiles.